# Unexpected MySql PoolExhaustedException

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, spring-data-jpa, database-connection, amazon-rds

I am running two EC2 instances on AWS to serve my application one for each. Each application can open up to 100 connections to MySql for default. For database I use RDS and t2.medium instance which can handle 312 connections at a time.

In general, my connection size does not get larger than 20. When I start sending notifications to the users to come to the application, the connection size increases a lot (which is expected.). In some cases, MySql connections increases unexpectedly and my application starts to throw **PoolExhaustedException**:

```
PoolExhaustedException: [pool-7-thread-92] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
```

When I check the database connections from Navicat, I see that there are about 200 connections and all of them are sleeping. I do not understand why the open connections are not used. I use standard Spring Data Jpa to save and read my entities which means I do not open or close the connections manually.

Unless I shut down one of the instance and the mysql connections are released, both instances do not response at all.

You can see the mysql connection size change graphic [**here**](https://ibb.co/dOZDRK), and a piece of log [**here**](https://ibb.co/dd3CLe).